# Script Not Working for User With Read Permissions

Tags: javascript, permissions, access-denied

I have a workflow that sends emails out. When a user receives the email, there is a hyperlink called Review. When user clicks on Review, the  value of the column called ReviewStatus on the Improvement List  will be changed to Requested. I have a script below that handles this on a Content Editor Web Part:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("getSetListItem");
        var listItem;
        var list;
        var clientContext;
        var siteUrl = "https://contoso.com/process/";
        function getSetListItem() {
            this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
            if (this.clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null) {
                var webSite = clientContext.get_web();
                var itemID = parseInt(GetUrlKeyValue('ID'));
                this.list = webSite.get_lists().getByTitle("Improvement");
                this.listItem = list.getItemById(itemID);
                clientContext.load(this.listItem);
                this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnLoadSuccess),
Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnLoadFailed));
            }
        } 
        function OnLoadSuccess(sender, args) {
            var value = this.listItem.get_item("ReviewStatus");
            this.listItem.set_item("ReviewStatus", "Requested");
            this.listItem.update();
            this.clientContext.load(this.listItem);
            this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnLoadSuccess1),
Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnLoadFailed));
        } 
        function OnLoadSuccess1(sender, args) {
            alert(this.listItem.get_item("ReviewStatus"));
        } 
        function OnLoadFailed(sender, args) {
            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
                
        </script>
```

The above works for me but I have Site Col Admin permissions. When a user with Read permissions clicks on the hyperlink it takes them to the page where the CEWP is and they get the below message:

[image]

I know it's permissions but what can I do to make it work for users who doesn't have the permissions? By the way, the client wants to keep the permissions to Read Only for users so there's nothing I can do about that.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Client-side, the only idea I have is to create an independent list, using the javascript to add an item to that list containing the ID of the original item. Then run a workflow on the new list that uses an impersonation step to set the ReviewStatus field in the item with matching ID.

Comment: I'm sorry I think I understand but wanted clarification. By doing your method it would only update the new list and not the original list where I want it to happen right?

Comment: After an item is added the new list, a workflow would start on it. This workflow would use an impersonation step to change the item in the original list. (Update List action)

Answer (score 0):

You are updating the list item with read permission using below code which is definitely not going to work.

```
this.listItem.set_item("ReviewStatus", "Requested");
this.listItem.update();
```

You **can not update a listitem without having permissions** on it. Running with Elevated privileges is the solution for your problem (Server). Apart from that i don't think there is a solution for it, because it would be a security issue in SharePoint.

Otherwise you can check other impersonation methods for this.

[How to Programmatically Impersonate Users in SharePoint](http://www.sharepointdeveloperhq.com/2009/04/how-to-programmatically-impersonate-users-in-sharepoint/)

[Impersonation in SharePoint 2010](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/433494/Impersonation-in-SharePoint)

Comment: Is my information useful for you?

Comment: Did you find this above information useful for you?